# using GPU in optimization in R (OpenCL)?

Tags: r, opencl, mathematical-optimization

based on an idea from another thread, I was hoping you could help me out with this idea / push me in the right direction.

I have seen an example of OpenCL, which didn't look too complicated for basic calculations, so I hope to just rewrite the function for numerical gradient the optimization routine uses in the OpenCL language, and squeeze it in the optimizer function, so everytime I would optimize some function, it would do the independent calculations in the GPU.

**Idea**: Use gpu for calculation of functionals and gradients during the optimizations (e.g. nlminb()

**Problems**:
1, How to tap the optimization routine? (I can't seem to locate the C file of which does the optimisation)

2,Can I just replace the gradient calculation with what I prepare for GPU?

3,Does anyone got something similar to work? Any ideas, notes?

Thank you and have a nice day!

PS: If you think it wouldn't speed up the optim, it's hard to code / hard to do, etc. please let me know! I'm very inexperienced and lousy "programmer".

Answer (score 0):

You could compile R linked to one of the OpenCL optimized BLAS libraries. But based on the attempts to speed up R with other BLAS libraries the results might be limited to [special cases.](http://www.cybaea.net/Blogs/Faster-R-through-better-BLAS.html)  Yours may be one of them though.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I had no idea about this. Bud do I understand correctly that it will intervene with my routines where I explicitly run computations on multiple cores? (mclapply)

Comment: No, I believe it's just the opposite. When running explicitly multicore commands that will happen whether compiled with optimized BLAS or not.  What this will do is speed up underlying commands where you aren't making such a request.  You're also confusing the link I sent you with what you want to do.  You want OpenCL optimized BLAS.  I remember one written for AMD GPUs but I don't know about general OpenCL optimized.

Comment: I understood the part that it will speed up everything. I just know that I wouldn't be able to code a new BLAS anyway. I have to wait for a ready-made solution when it comes to BLAS, because only thing I would be able to code is the cuda calculation of gradients if I knew how to tap the optimizer function.